# How to monkeypatch a single variable value in pytest

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a function:

```
def test():
    url = "/test/pvc/name"
    if "pvc" in url:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Now to test this function I want to patch the `url` variable. How can I do that? I tried:

```
monkeypatch.setattr('url', "/test")
```

But this does not seem to work. I keep getting:

```
    def derive_importpath(import_path, raising):
        if not isinstance(import_path, six.string_types) or "." not in import_path:
>           raise TypeError("must be absolute import path string, not %r" % (import_path,))
E           TypeError: must be absolute import path string, not 'url'
```

Comment: Why don't you refactor that function to the simpler `return True`?

Answer (score 5):

Try getting the URL as a parameter with default values, like this:

```
def test(url='/test/pvc/name'):
    if "pvc" in url:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Now, when you call it you can set the URL that you want. Your function is more abstract and useful.

Just a little stretch, you can rewrite that function like this:

```
def test(url='test/pvc/name'):
    return 'pvc' in url
```

It would return `True` if pvc is in the variable and `False` if not

---

Also, `monkeypatch` is used to patch imported modules. We never mock a variable inside a function. It is against the whole idea of TDD. When doing unit tests you should mock all imported dependencies, but you should leave the variables and data inside a function untouched.